# Is it possible to match an intent-filter's pathPattern in a case insensitive way?

Tags: android, android-intent

We have an android application that can open certain types of files.  I have declared an intent filter in the AndroidManifest.xml file for each one like so (sample extension: ext):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext"/>

        </intent-filter>
```

Everything is fine when opening files such as `myFile.ext`, however if a file was named `myFile.EXT` or `myFile.ExT`, etc the intent-filter does not seem to pick it up.  Aside from enumerating all possible capitalization permutations in the intent filter is there a way to specify a case insensitive match?

The docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) mention other attributes of the data element are case sensitive but make no mention of it for pathPattern.  I tried adding the java instruction for case insensitive regex to the pattern which resulted in `"(?i).*\\.ext"` and OR'ing multile together like `".*\\.ext|.*\\.EXT"` but that did not seem to work either.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:pathPattern` is not a full regex. It's a "[simple glob](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html#PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB)" which only supports a very small subset of what regexes can do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the best solution I have reached is two repeat the same data attributes but with slightly different `pathPatthern` to cover all cases.

In your case:

```
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.Ext"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.eXt"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.exT"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.EXt"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.eXT"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.ExT"/>
<data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.EXT"/>
```

Comment: That mimeType will open every single file on the device.  **pathPattern** will do nothing here.